# I need to construct an IPv6 packet with extension headers.

Tags: java, c++, python, ipv6, packets

I have been researching for days now and i am getting pretty desperate.

I am trying to construct an IPv6 packet WITH extension headers in any language possible(must be through a programming language to automate some tasks), so that i can send them to a series of sites and test compatibility with those extension headers.

What i have tried up to now: 
JAVA-- JPCAP this however does not support extension headers at all
PYTHON-- Scapy with Pydev This however only supports three out of 9 extension headers. At the very least i want hop by hop, fragmentation, routing, encapsulation, authentication and maybe destination options (6/9).

So now i am out of ideas. What is the best tool to use in order to construct an ipv6 packet from the ground up with only default content (just the presence of the extension headers is enough in order to test comaptibility) so payload would normally be empty. Only in packets containing fragmentation it would not in order to increase packet size above MTU.

Any ideas? 
I am pretty desperate any input is well appreciated. 
Thanks 
Martinos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like scapy may have all that you need or be extensible to do so.  See [extending scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/build_dissect.html) and a couple of pdfs that discuss what you need [IPv6 Extension Headers - New Features, and New Attack](https://www.ernw.de/download/IPv6%20Extension%20Headers%20-%20New%20Features,%20and%20New%20Attack%20Vectors.pdf) & [attacking ipv6 implementation using fragmentation - Black Hat](http://media.blackhat.com/bh-eu-12/Atlasis/bh-eu-12-Atlasis-Attacking_IPv6-Slides.pdf)

Comment: hey the 2nd link is not working for some reason IPv6 Extension Headers - New Features, and New Attack